# R - Secondary Axis - ggplot - Right axis not scaling correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe example:

```
Date = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
m = c(17409, 18617, 19982, 21018, 22580, 23669, 25048)
GDP = c(0.0101, 0.0103, 0.0107, 0.0109, 0.0112, 0.0113, 0.0116)

df = data.frame(Data, m, GDP)
```

I am trying to put the line (GDP) on the right secondary y axis.

I have done the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = m), size = 1, color = "darkblue", fill = "white") +
  geom_line(aes(y= GDP/20000000), size = 1.5, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1834862))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

So the secondary axis is showing, but the red line (GDP) is not scaled correctly. From my reading, in the sec_axis part I divided by 1834862 to scale, but its just not working (or maybe I am not understanding correctly). I have looked at other examples on stack overflow and I am still stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to multiply, not divide. And shouldn't it be `GDP*1834862`?

Comment: I tried to multiple it, and same issue. Also, if I put GDP it says object not found (sec_axis( ~.GDP*1834862)). If I put df$GDP, I get the same error but for df

Comment: Thank you Rui, Allan explained what you meant. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full reprex. Like Rui says, you need to do the inverse operation to your data that you do with the y x axis scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Date = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)
m = c(17409, 18617, 19982, 21018, 22580, 23669, 25048)
GDP = c(0.0101, 0.0103, 0.0107, 0.0109, 0.0112, 0.0113, 0.0116)

df = data.frame(Date, m, GDP)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = m), size = 1, color = "darkblue", fill = "white") +
  geom_line(aes(y= GDP*1834862), size = 1.5, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1834862))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh I see!!! I was doing the multiplication on the wrong line. Thank you very much Allan!